# Running a list of Computer Names against a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have to add a large number of computers to a vendor database using an encrypted stored procedure. Is it possible to write a T-SQL statement that will pass each of these computer names to the stored procedure from a file like a CSV or from a temporary table?

Please let me know what other information would be helpful in answering this question.

Comment: Is it possible - most likely - what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the computer names into a temp table, you can loop through the names and execute the procedure like this:

```
create table #ComputerNames (ComputerName varchar(100));
-- insert #ComputerNames
declare @ComputerName varchar(100);
set @ComputerName = (select min(ComputerName) from #ComputerNames);
while @ComputerName is not null
begin
   exec xxx.YourStoredProcedure @parameter = @ComputerName;
   -- Increment the loop:
   set @ComputerName = (select min(@ComputerName) from #ComputerNames where ComputerName > @ComputerName);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I will give this a try.